# Snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks

Tags: linux, package-managers, apparmor, snap

I have been using snap for some time but after a recent upgrade, I get this error when I try opening any application

```
Snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be.
Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
```

I have tried various fixes but it keeps getting worse. Any idea on what I should do?

I also tried `sudo apt purge snapd snap-confine && sudo apt install -y snapd` but when I try opening pycharm-community, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Don't try using this command: `sudo apt purge snapd snap-confine`

That will uninstall a lot of applications and that's not what you normally want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
systemctl enable --now apparmor.service    
systemctl enable --now snapd.apparmor.service
```

[from here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/kali-2021-snap-confine-has-elevated-permissions-and-is-not-confined-but-should-be-refusing-to-continue-to-avoid-permission-escalation-attacks/27164/4)

Comment: you need to add **sudo** before both commands if you are not authorized user.

Answer (score 66):

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine*
```

Fixes it. No restart required.

Comment: After power failure i can't start slack, vscode. This advice was helpfull for me. Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: **It doesn't work for me**, now it says *"cannot change profile for the next exec call: No such file or directory"*. I did previously due to another error  `apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*` `apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine*` now with this asnwer it's still broken. keep on search

Comment: This is working for me but temporarily. After reboot, the same problem pursues, and I have to run these commands again. Is there a permanent solution ?

Comment: sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
was enough for me!

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me

```
service snapd.apparmor start
```

(It needs the root.)

Comment: I tried that but every after I restart my system the error reoccurs.

Comment: @ROOT-X17 `sudo systemctl start snapd.apparmor` should mark this service to auto-start

Comment: This one perfectly worked on me. Thank you

Answer (score 20):

From https://apparmor.net/

> AppArmor (app-armor) is an effective and easy-to-use Linux application security
> system. AppArmor proactively protects the operating system and
> applications from external or internal threats, even zero-day attacks,
> by enforcing good behavior and preventing both known and unknown
> application flaws from being exploited.

```bash
    # start the appormor system
    sudo systemctl start apparmor 
    # parse and reload all apparmor profiles of installed snap applications 
    sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me on Kali Linux:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine*
systemctl enable --now snapd.apparmor.service
```

Comment: Worked on my Xubuntu 22.04, too. I tried the other approaches below but they didn't help.

Comment: This worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS).

Answer (score 3):

This command helped me fix `docker-compose`:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*
```

You can check if docker-compose works by using command:

```
docker-compose version
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by a bad AppArmor profile being present and loaded in complain (or enforce?) mode in

`/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.snap`

This apparently lead to snap not being able to determine the number of the snap and therefor caused a bad profile to be added to AppArmor.

"aa-status" outputed lines such as:

`/usr/bin/snap//null-/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine`

for being in enforce mode

I moved that file (`/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.snap`) to my home directory, ran "sudo aa-remove-unknown" and "sudo systemctl restart apparmor" after which everything was back to normal.

However I don't know the origins of `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.snap` so keep in mind that there might be something wrong with the system.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using snap to run scrcpy. I tried this suggestion first and it worked:

> sudo snap refresh

(This suggestion found at https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/249)

Answer (score 0):

This command also worked in my case :-

```
$ sudo service snapd.apparmor start
$ whatsdesk
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is really works is [pavlikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14373939/pavlikooo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70141450/12634253)

But in some cases, it also would be better to execute first:

```
sudo systemctl enable snapd
```

And don't forget to add sudo to [pavlikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14373939/pavlikooo)'s commands if you don't have special permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed AppArmor was not running. Some other bug in AppArmor will disable the whole snap! This has to be fixed before AppArmor can start.

```
Nov 21 00:24:40 kfc-XPS-15-9560 apparmor.systemd[201673]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.tcpdump in profile /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.tcpdump at line 64: Could not open 'local/usr.sbin.tcpdump'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me after executing

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine*
```

i got an error of:

> missing profile snap.docker.compose.
> Please make sure that the snapd.apparmor service is enabled and started

It was fixed with

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.compose
```

following this askubuntu thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248349/docker-compose-denied-by-apparmor-outside-of-home-how-to-fix

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl enable snapd.service   
sudo systemctl start snapd.service
service snapd.apparmor start
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another solution in case you've messed up with apparmor profiles and a service restart is not enough for you.

This would probably apply to you if you used [aa-genprof](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/aa-genprof.8.html) to create a new profile of an app under the management of snapd, in my case it was VSCode.

Snap core package was broken so new snaps installation were also failing.

If you can't remove Firefox snap due to
`Unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/` try unmounting it `umount /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell`, before `snap remove --purge firefox`

```bash
mkdir -p ~/profile-backups ~/profile-backups/var ~/profile-backups/local

# Stop services before moving around profiles
sudo systemctl stop snapd.apparmor
sudo systemctl stop apparmor

find /etc/apparmor.d -type f -name "*snapd*"
# -> check what you find and the edit time, new stuff is suspicious stuff
ls -lt /etc/apparmor.d

sudo mv /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine* ~/profile-backups
sudo mv /etc/apparmor.d/local/*snap-confine* ~/profile-backups/local
sudo mv /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*confine* ~/profile-backups/var

sudo apt purge snapd

sudo aa-remove-unknown
# -> restart

sudo apt install -y --install-recommends snapd
```

[Install as classic](https://snapcraft.io/docs/install-modes) or from apt only the trusted few packages that have issues  with apparmor like starship or vscode

```bash
sudo snap install --classic what_you_like_to_not_be_restricted --channel latest/stable
```

Then install [Firefox](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04), [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions)... from apt or official deb or as classic snaps.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. It also makes it so that it automatically starts at launch.

```
$ cd /snap/bin
$ sudo service start snapd
$ sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
$ sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.service
```

just copy it and it should work(at least it did for me)
and if you want to disable it just type

```
$ sudo systemctl disable snapd.service
```