# Snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Is there a permanent fix?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apparmor, snap

lately I've been getting an error for some applications. They are not working as normally before. I think some system update caused this issue. I'm using ubuntu 22.04.

I've already check this: [Snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053614/snap-confine-has-elevated-permissions-and-is-not-confined-but-should-be-refusin)

and [Diego V's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065300/7871601) is working for me. However, it only works until system reboot, after system restart the problem is re-occurring, and I have to do the fix (with the cmds) every time after reboot. Is there a permanent fix for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue (also on Ubuntu 22.04) and found that apparmor was inactive:
$ systemctl status apparmor
I enabled apparmor:
$ sudo systemctl enable apparmor
which starts appormor at boot (it does not start it in the current session: sudo systemctl start apparmor).

https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-enable-disable-apparmor-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

I don't have rights to comment so I can only reply here that it remains an issu and like Null I seek an answer other than provided by Diego V, which works until reboot where apparmor is already enabled/running so doesn't require trekerj's answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).